# Received data add to a variable from arduino

Tags: android, arduino, android-bluetooth

I want to add data received from Arduino to a individual variable. From Arduino i will send speed, pressure, torque data.
Speed - 2 byte(0-3500rpm), pressure 4 sensors(0-10.0bar) - 4 bytes, torque - 2 bytes(0-500Nm). I think the best way would be to send it in one message? or better is to send separate messages?
Maybe there is a way to get data from string if i would send message like this.

`s{B1 B2}s p{B1 B2 B3 B4}p t{B1 B2}t`

at the moment i am trying to do something like this:

```
  private String output = "";
  private String speed = "0";
  private String speedStart = "s{";
  private String speedEnd = "}s";
  private String pressureStart = "p{";
  private String pressureEnd = "}p";
  private String torqueStart = "t{";
  private String torqueEnd = "}t";
```

...

```
byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
            Log.d(TAG, "readMessage="+ readMessage); // For debugging 
            output += readMessage;
            if (output.startsWith(speedStart)){ // At the moment it works only with message s{data}s
                if (output.endsWith(speedEnd)){
                    speed = output;
            txtArduino.setText("Speed: "+ speed);
          Log.d(TAG, "Output="+ output); // For debugging
                output = "";
                }
            }
            else{ // If received string wihtout proper start delete it
                Log.d(TAG, "Output from else before delete="+ output); // For debugging
             output = "";} // If received string wihtout
```

Is there more efficient way to get from arduino? To map it maybe or whatever what works.

Also i should mention that sometimes android separates messages from arduino for example:

Send string `"Hello world\n"`

Receive string in 2 messages:

`"H"
"ello world\n"`

**EDIT**

After few tests run i noticed that Bluetooth is doing crazy things.
I am sending `#S0270Pa05Pb09Pc10Pd01T013` without new line so there are 26 bytes.

I have

```
case BLUETOOTH_RECEIVED:
        byte[] buffer = (byte[])msg.obj;
        int len = msg.arg1;
        Log.i(LOGGER_TAG, String.format("*** CASE *** Received: " + "%d bytes", len));
        if (len > 0 && buffer != null) {
            onBluetoothRead(buffer, len);
        }
        break;
```

then

```
private void onBluetoothRead(byte[] buffer, int len) {      
    String output = new String(buffer, 0, len); // Add read buffer to new string
    outputTemp += output;
    valid = valid + len;
    //Log.i(LOGGER_TAG, String.format("*** onBluetoothRead *** Received: "+ output + " , " + ", %d lenght", len));
    if (valid == 26){
        Log.i(LOGGER_TAG, String.format("*** subString *** from: " + outputTemp));
         //01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 
         //#  S  0  2  7  0  P  a  0  5  P  b  0  9  P  c  1  0  P  d  0  1  T  0  1  3  \n
    m_deviceOutputSpeed.setText("RPM = " + outputTemp.substring(2, 6));
    m_deviceOutputPrs.setText(
            "Pressure 1 = " + outputTemp.substring(8, 10) + 
            "\nPressure 2 = " + outputTemp.substring(12, 14)+
            "\nPressure 3 = " + outputTemp.substring(16, 18)+
            "\nPressure 4 = " + outputTemp.substring(20, 22));
    outputTemp = "";
    valid = 0;
    }}
```

And LogCat:

```
09-16 09:14:34.344: I/DeviceActivity(17610): Bluetooth connected
09-16 09:14:35.334: I/DeviceActivity(17610): *** CASE *** Received: 1 bytes
09-16 09:14:35.344: I/DeviceActivity(17610): *** CASE *** Received: 9 bytes
09-16 09:14:35.344: I/DeviceActivity(17610): *** CASE *** Received: 9 bytes
09-16 09:14:35.344: I/DeviceActivity(17610): *** CASE *** Received: 7 bytes
09-16 09:14:35.344: I/DeviceActivity(17610): *** subString *** from: Pd01T0130Pd01T0130Pd01T013
```

What the hell is going on? :)

**EDIT 2**

Added 10ms delay between sending data:

```
void send_data(){
  mySerial.write(start);
  delay(10);
  mySerial.write(speed);
  delay(10);
  mySerial.write(prs1);
  delay(10);
  mySerial.write(prs2);
  delay(10);
  mySerial.write(prs3);
  delay(10);
  mySerial.write(prs4);
  delay(10);
  mySerial.write(torque);
}
```

And i can see that the data corruption also happens in android... I will pull my hair of my head!!!

```
09-16 14:06:51.364: I/DeviceActivity(29651): *** CASE *** Received: #S, 2 bytes
09-16 14:06:51.404: I/DeviceActivity(29651): *** CASE *** Received: 1050, 4 bytes
09-16 14:06:51.404: I/DeviceActivity(29651): *** CASE *** Received: Pa05, 4 bytes
09-16 14:06:51.404: I/DeviceActivity(29651): *** CASE *** Received: Pb, 2 bytes
09-16 14:06:51.404: I/DeviceActivity(29651): *** CASE *** Received: 09, 2 bytes
09-16 14:06:51.424: I/DeviceActivity(29651): *** CASE *** Received: Pc10, 4 bytes
09-16 14:06:51.444: I/DeviceActivity(29651): *** CASE *** Received: Pd01, 4 bytes
09-16 14:06:51.454: I/DeviceActivity(29651): *** CASE *** Received: T0, 2 bytes
09-16 14:06:51.454: I/DeviceActivity(29651): *** CASE *** Received: 13, 2 bytes
09-16 14:06:51.454: I/DeviceActivity(29651): *** subString *** from: #SPa05Pb05Pb09Pc10Pd011313
```

Sometimes get cloned data...

```
09-19 10:29:58.184: I/DeviceActivity(9277): *** Received ***
09-19 10:29:58.184: I/DeviceActivity(9277): *** CASE *** ", 1 bytes
09-19 10:29:58.184: I/DeviceActivity(9277): *** Started ***
09-19 10:29:58.184: I/DeviceActivity(9277): *** Finished ***
09-19 10:29:58.184: I/DeviceActivity(9277): *** Received ***
09-19 10:29:58.184: I/DeviceActivity(9277): *** CASE *** "code": ", 9 bytes
09-19 10:29:58.194: I/DeviceActivity(9277): *** Started ***
09-19 10:29:58.194: I/DeviceActivity(9277): *** Finished ***
09-19 10:29:58.194: I/DeviceActivity(9277): *** Received ***
09-19 10:29:58.194: I/DeviceActivity(9277): *** CASE *** "code": " , 10 bytes
09-19 10:29:58.194: I/DeviceActivity(9277): *** Started ***
09-19 10:29:58.194: I/DeviceActivity(9277): *** Finished ***
09-19 10:29:58.194: I/DeviceActivity(9277): *** Received ***
09-19 10:29:58.194: I/DeviceActivity(9277): *** CASE *** "code": ", 9 bytes
09-19 10:29:58.194: I/DeviceActivity(9277): *** Started ***
09-19 10:29:58.204: I/DeviceActivity(9277): *** Finished ***
09-19 10:29:58.214: I/DeviceActivity(9277): *** Received ***
09-19 10:29:58.214: I/DeviceActivity(9277): *** CASE *** DZ"}, 4 bytes
09-19 10:29:58.214: I/DeviceActivity(9277): *** Started ***
09-19 10:29:58.214: I/DeviceActivity(9277): *** Parsing JSON ***""code": ""code": " "code": "DZ"}
```

Comment: Ok, the EDIT part shows a weird behaviour. I'd try to see if 1) you actually send the right data (e.g. by sniffing on the data line between BT and Arduino). 2) if it works well, try to print only what you get (`private void onBluetoothRead(byte[] buffer, int len) { String output = new String(buffer, 0, len); Log.i(LOGGER_TAG, String.format("*** onBluetoothRead *** Received: "+ output + " , " + ", %d lenght", len)); }` And then check what you get. After this you have to make more improvements (check for the START char, handle multiple messages in the same packet...)

Comment: @frarugi87 its always nice to get ideas from smart ppl. I done what you suggested, but i can't understand the BT behaviour. Received even more interesting data... If you have time plz look at EDIT2, CASES are what i received, subString after appending it to one string

Comment: I assume that you sent `#S1050Pa05Pb09Pc10Pd01T013` instead of `#S0270Pa05Pb09Pc10Pd01T013`. If that is true, it looks like the usual concurrency problem. If you do something like `case BLUETOOTH_RECEIVED: Log.i(LOGGER_TAG, "Received")...` and `private void onBluetoothRead(byte[] buffer, int len) {Log.i(LOGGER_TAG, "Started") ...your code... Log.i(LOGGER_TAG, "Finished")}` i think that, instead of getting the sequence `Received,started,finished,Received, started, finished` you will get something like `received,started,received,started,finished,finished` when problems arise.

Comment: If the problem is what I guessed, a possible solution (provided that the case is not executed asynchronously) is to make a copy of the byte array in buffer (instead than just a cast) and pass that to the function. I think that `byte[] buffer = ((byte[])msg.obj).clone();` will do the work. Try and let us know..

Comment: Tested it, clone() does not give any treatment... it still gets by 3 messages. @frarugi87 Do you know how BT decides when it is a new messages? Maybe baud rate is affecting some how? Arduino<->BT module communicates at 9600BDR. I am now doing it with JSON and sending test `String {"name": "Angola", "code": "AO"}`, + added the corrupted LogCat

Comment: Reading my questions after so many years feels so embarrassing... Thanks all, everyone starts somewhere :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could send It as JSON object from Arduino like this

```
{
    "speedStart":10,
    "speedEnd":10,
    ...
}
```

You could make some helper methods for building JSON in arduino:

```
Serial.print("{");
printIntParameter("speedStart", 10);
Serial.print(",");
printIntParameter("speedEnd", 10);
Serial.print("}");

void printIntParameter(char* name, int value) {
    Serial.print("\""); Serial.print(name); Serial.print("\"");
    Serial.print(":");
    Serial.print(value);
}
```

In Android you start buffering JSON when you got `{` and stop on `}` and then parse this JSON from String to object using https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: JSON is really versatile and powerful. But... In this case it is too complicated; you can used a fixed-length string and you save a lot of time (remember that when you send something on the serial line the microcontroller waits). In the example I made in my answer, the json (without carriage returns nor tabs) can be: `{ 'speed': 270, 'pressure1': 5, 'pressure2': 9, 'pressure3': 10, 'pressure4': 1, 'torque': 13 }` which is 95 bytes long: you are sending almost 70 chars more (length +265%) and.. They are useless! ;)

Comment: But you could save a bit more space by removing whitespace and using shorter names like this: `{"a":270,"b":2...}` - not sure If valid in gson but you could try also removing `"`

Comment: Hm, data should not be corrupted hm, Is not that problem of bt module?

Answer (score 1):

You have to choose if you want it to be efficient or easily readable.

I mean if you have to send 485 Nm of torque, you can send

1. Binary representation (0x01, 0xE5, i.e. 2 bytes)
2. Ascii representation ('4', '8', '5', i.e. 3 bytes)

The first method is more efficient; the second one is easier to see on, for instance, a serial monitor.

In both cases i suggest you to use fixed-length messages. Use a special char to notify the microcontroller that the transmission began, then send all the data sequentially (and every token has to be a fixed lenght one). So the microcontroller will know when the message ends.

With a "fixed length token" i mean that if you send a string representation you have to insert '0's on the left (padding) because otherwise you will lose the position of the other elements.

In the binary representation you will have problems because the "special character" can be also in the middle of the packet; so you have to handle it.

Just an example of packet with a string representation:

```
Speed - 270 rpm
Pressure 5 bar 9 bar 10 bar 1 bar
Torque - 13 Nm
Packet: #S0270Pa05Pb09Pc10Pd01T013
```

Here i used # as the "packet start" character and added S, Pa, Pb, Pc, Pd and T as additional characters just to see it on the serial monitor (they are useless). More important: i used 4 chars fot the speed (0-3500 means that at most there are 4 chars), 2 chars for each of the pressures (because the highest value is 10, so 2 digits) and 3 for the torque.

Just one personal suggestions: avoid using something complicated like json or xml or other stuff like that; microcontrollers are not PCs, they have limited resources; if you can do something to make they wirk with fixed data (e.g. integers instead of floating points) they will work much much better.

BTW: of course you can get a split message. It's quite common in networking or when sending data. But.. if you have a fixed-length string you just wait for the correct number of chars - 26 in the example i showed you; if you don't receive them you just have to wait slightly more...

Comment: Thanks frarugi87 for nice answer. And how would you suggest to extract data from Packet? Like @Yuraj said, with JSON? Your both answer are quite well :)))

Comment: Well, since the string is "fixed format", you already know where the data is. So... SpeedString = ReceivedString.substring(2,5); once you have it in string you can convert it to a number with the parse functions.

Comment: I updated my question after few tests, read after **EDIT**. Something is going not good...